# Show that the following is not a complete residue system.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $m > 2$ and $a_1,...,a_m$ is a complete residue system (mod $m$) then $a_1^2,...,a_m^2$ is not.

I feel that it is very simple but I am not seeing a connection. I tried to make a connection that if $a_1,...,a_{\phi (m)}$ is a reduced residue system then $aa_1,...,aa_{\phi (m)}$ is also a reduced residue system, but I don't think that would help at all with the problem.

A complete residue system (mod $m$) is a set of integers which has m elements, consists of incongruent integers (mod $m$), and represents every residue class (mod $m$) exactly once.

Comment: **HINT**: $(-a)^2 = a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m\gt2$ then there are *distinct* indices $i$ and $j$ such that $a_i\equiv1$ mod $m$ and $a_j\equiv-1$ mod $m$ (since $1\not\equiv-1$ mod $m$ if $m\gt2$).  But then $a_i^2\equiv a_j^2$ mod $m$, so $a_1^2,\ldots,a_m^2$ can account for at most $m-1$ residues.